# How can I take a variable from the childComponent to ParentComponent ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a machine that show random quotes. I created new function component to take random colors for using them in parent component.But I cant take my **bgColor** constant to my parent component.I want to use **bgColor** in **App()** function as a style color.I know maybe i can create the child component inside the parent element.But i want to divide it, and working on partial on project.

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Color from "./color"

function App() {

  
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState([]);
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState([]);

  const getQuote = () => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1643 + 1);
    fetch('https://type.fit/api/quotes')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setText(result[random].text);
          setAuthor(result[random].author);
        },

        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getQuote();
  }, []);


const redirect=()=>{

  window.location.href= 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text='+encodeURIComponent('"' + text + '" ' + author)
  ;

}
console.log(props)
  return (
    <div
      className="d-flex flex-column  border border-primary w-50 shadow container"
      id="quote-box"
    >
      <h2 id="text" className="m-4">
        {text}
      </h2>
      <h4 id="author" className="text-info text-end m-3">
        {author}
      </h4>
      <button id="new-quote" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={getQuote}>
        New Quote
      </button>

      <a onClick={redirect}
 id="tweet-quote" className="mt-5">
        <i className="fab fa-twitter fa-1x"></i>
      </a>
      
      <Color/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Also this is my **childComponent**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
  
  export default function Color() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 120);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 120);
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 120);
    const bgColor = 'rgb(' + x + ',' + y + ',' + z + ')';



      return (
          <div>
              <App bgColor={bgColor}/>
          </div>
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use useContext hook and wrap your App component with it.
read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs-usecontext-hook

Comment: So how can  i use useContext in my project ?